# Shading only the background of title block in the title page with a particular beamer theme

Tags: beamer, color, titles, presentations, shading

Is it possible to only shade the background of the title box in the title page in a theme like Madrid?

I tried using

```
\setbeamercolor{title}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=blue}
```

but that only allows me to change the background into a particular color and not a gradient.

Comment: Related: [Changing the Title Frame color to a Gradient](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/285046/134144), [Vertical colour gradient in frametitle (beamer)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/334971/134144), [How can I have a horizontally shaded frametitle in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/226691/134144),...

Comment: I don't want that in the frame title but only in the title of the presentation, on the first page.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the tcolobox inner beamer theme.

The following code makes use of the new beamer title page templates, which will be included in beamer v3.70 or later. Until this is released, you can get the development version from https://github.com/josephwright/beamer

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\title{Title}

\useinnertheme{tcolorbox}
\addtobeamertemplate{title}{
  \begingroup
  \tcbset{
    enhanced,
    interior style={left color=blue,right color=green}
  }
}{\endgroup}

\begin{document}


    
\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{title}
content...
\end{block}
\end{frame}
        
    
\end{document}
```

[image]